# CSS-targeting the white page that Chrome displays for a split-second while loading

Tags: google-chrome, colors, css

When you click on a link in Chrome to go from page x to page y, for a split-second it displays a white empty page. I want to make that page black so it won't hurt my eyes.

Now, I'm a fresh graduate of this question:

[Hack Chrome to show its internal pages with black background](https://superuser.com/questions/591089/hack-chrome-to-show-its-internal-pages-with-black-background)

As the accepted answer suggests, I've customized my `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets\Custom.css` file.

It turns out that this file *is* able to target the split-second loading page! Yay! I was able to make that page black by putting a simple `html {background: black}` in `Custom.css`.

Problem is... The `Custom.css` file is applied to *all* web pages. This means that now I get a black background on all pages, which is something I *don't* want! (Because I already have an extension that flips the colors, and black flipped becomes white.)

My question is: **How do I write CSS in `Custom.css` that targets *only* the white page that Chrome shows for a split-second while loading a webpage?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question at hand, I don't think it is possible to target the page (or this state of a page) through CSS alone.

I created a quick Chrome extension to make every page background black until the page is loaded.

You can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/oliversalzburg/dbd) and the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-by-default/fjdgnklblnkfodhliojchndbhjomcnfh).

Please note that I only wrote this for this specific question and have not done extensive testing. I already noticed an issue on Google Searches. <s>I use Google Instant and it seems like the `window.onload` event the extension relies on is never fired.</s> It should work pretty reliably in version 0.2 now.

Feel free to report bugs on GitHub, I'm likely to fix them.

Comment: However, when I use it pages still show some white when loading. I think the problem is that the extensions are loaded with some small delay, not immediately upon opening a page.

Comment: I have an idea on how to resolve it: Can you have your extension add a permanent class to the `html` element? It can be called whatever you want and it should do nothing. But when it'll exist, I could target `html:not([your_class_name])` in the `Custom.css` file, and then I could make pages black even earlier.

Comment: @RamRachum: Right, the extension runs when the `<html>` and a few other elements are loaded. Then the extension still needs to run. So there is a certain period where you could still see white. I didn't see this happening in my testing, so I assumed it wasn't an issue. I'll add a class `dark-by-default` through the extension, see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Actually it can be an HTML attribute, which might be better. But I think a class would work as well.

Comment: @RamRachum: I added that feature. Please use GitHub/Chrome Web Store or email me directly for further feedback on the extension. That makes it easier to keep things organized :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure this can't be done. The "page" that you see for a split second isn't actually a separate page but merely the unconstructed page that is being downloaded. The only way around it would be for all pages you visit to explicitly specify a background that would then override the one in Custom.css.

The only way I can think to get around it would be to run some JavaScript (using something like greasemonkey) when pages are loaded to remove the black background if it isn't needed.

EDIT: 
Actually, after a bit of thinking this may do what you want (with a little tweaking maybe)

```
html {
    -webkit-animation: fadebackground 1s linear 0 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadebackground {
    0% {
        background: black;
    }
    100% {
        background: none;
    }
}
```

This will start off with a black background and fade to none after a second. 
You can find a pretty thoughrough writeup of the -webkit-animation property here http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/14/the-guide-to-css-animation-principles-and-examples/

Comment: The fading background is an impressive hack. Unfortunately it doesn't work. Sometimes it's too short, and I get a blast of white, and sometimes it's too long, and then it remains black too much and the High Contrast extension flips it to white and then my eyes get blasted again.

Comment: I think the too short would be due to the background colour being set in the pages CSS causing it to change. You could try tweaking the timings and percentages until you get something that suits.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets\Custom.css`

```
body:empty {
    background: black;
}
```