# Chrome extension that predictably assigns ANY attribute to the <html> tag

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I need a Chrome extension that assigns *any kind of* attribute to the `<html>` tag. The only requirements are that it does so predictably, so I know I can always count on it setting that attribute, and also that the extension doesn't do anything obnoxious.

I don't care what the extension is for, I just want that attribute.

The reason I want this is because I want to construct a selector that selects the `<html>` tag just before the extensions load, and then deselects it as soon as they load, for [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/591322/css-targeting-the-white-page-that-chrome-displays-for-a-split-second-while-loadi/592084?iemail=1&noredirect=1#592084).)

**Is anyone familiar with such an extension?**

Comment: If you still need it (after my answer to your other question), let me know. It would be trivial to construct this based on [Dark by Default](https://github.com/oliversalzburg/dbd).

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Yep, I want it, thanks! And you should post it here as an answer and get the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the extension [Dark by Default](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-by-default/fjdgnklblnkfodhliojchndbhjomcnfh) which applies a black background to the `<html>` element as soon as it becomes available for manipulation.

The extension is also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/oliversalzburg/dbd).

As of version 0.3, the extension will leave a CSS class on the `<html>` element `dark-by-default`, you could use that CSS class for your selector.

I actually started using the extension myself. It goes very well with the [Super User Dark Theme](https://github.com/oliversalzburg/superuser-dark-theme) :D

Answer (score 0):

Chrome natively supports user scripts,
so [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) scripts also work in Google Chrome (and not only in Firefox).

For starters, see :

[Beginner Guide for Greasemonkey Scripts in Google Chrome](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/24790/beginner-guide-for-greasemonkey-scripts-in-google-chrome/).
[Greasemonkey Manual:Getting Help](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Greasemonkey_Manual:Getting_Help)

You might also have a look at these depositories of Greasemonkey Scripts :

[Userscript.org](http://userscripts.org/) 
[Userstyles.org](http://userstyles.org/)

Comment: That's a good option, but if I could get a regular extension that I don't have to write or maintain across computers, that'd be better.

Comment: The extension [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) may help.