# Applying custom style to internal Chrome pages

Tags: google-chrome, themes

I want to apply custom styles to the internal pages used by chrome. (Like the new tab page.)

I used to do what is said here:

[Hack Chrome to show its internal pages with black background](https://superuser.com/questions/591089/hack-chrome-to-show-its-internal-pages-with-black-background)

But it no longer works because Chrome 32 doesn't support Custom.css anymore.

Is there a way to style internal Chrome pages in Chrome 33+?

Comment: Other vendors allow freedom and will provide better flexibility. You could try a Chrome variant like (Chromium?), Iron, Comodo, Torch, etc. Most tend to forgo the iron-fisted, tyranical, dictatorial, fascism that Google has come to embrace and enforce on users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so I searched a bit on this and found that you **can** emulate `custom.css` using Extensions.

Here's how to do it:

1. Create a directory and put the files we will create in this guide inside it.
2. Go to `chrome://extensions`
3. Select "Developer mode"
4. Click on "Load unpacked extension"
5. Select the directory you just created.

Now, open the directory you just created and create these files:

### manifest.json

```js
{
   "content_scripts": [{
      "js": [ "inst.js" ],
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
   }], 
   "key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC4r/pUHVPYQTn7vu3YHT52I0SKM15OBOTi0Jii4q5Koxd3Gdc/WXdqC2YgMA25J5PRiSubu/nHFf12Ubp3OZyNqB3j45ZscQ+tH1bwcV+cqdvv/Ik6VQaS6/qLmenLdFPKOCg/g1L1iKZu6Jjny6GlovpBj+7gjWQZBIoGBd70HQIDAQAB",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Emulate Custom.css",
   "version": "1.0",
   "web_accessible_resources": [ "Custom.css" ]
}
```

### inst.js

```js
if (location.protocol === 'chrome:') (function() {
    'use strict';
    var l = document.createElement('link');
    l.rel = 'stylesheet';
    l.href = chrome.runtime.getURL('Custom.css');
    document.head.appendChild(l);
})();
```

### Custom.css

```
/* whatever you had in your Custom.css */
```

This will insert the CSS only to Chrome Internal pages since they all have `chrome:` protocol. Every rule you add to `Custom.css` here will be inserted to Chrome's Internal Pages.

Note that, the New Tab page is **NOT** Chrome's Internal page now. It is loaded from cache of `https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab?espv=210&ie=UTF-8`. This URL breaks in non-Chromium browsers and redirects to homepage on Chromium Browsers except Google Chrome 32+.

EDIT: I have found a setting in `chrome://flags` which enable extensions on `chrome://` pages. Available here: `chrome://flags/#extensions-on-chrome-urls`. But again, in this case you'll have to specify the scpecific chrome internal pages instead of `<all_urls>` in `manifest.json`, eg: `chrome://newtab`, etc etc.

Comment: Tried it, it didn't work. I tried the settings page and it didn't apply there. Also, I'd prefer a solution that doesn't use an extension because these might load too late for some uses. Something more internal to Chrome would be better.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just realized that Google disabled running of Content Scripts on Chrome's internal pages. So far, I have found no way to modify Internal Pages.

Comment: That’s not new; extensions have *never* applied to Chrome pages. There is (was?) only a very limited set of things extensions could do to Chrome itself (e.g., replace the NTP), but other things like Google’s own screenshot extension could not work on `chrome://` pages.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for correcting me. But I thought they did, coz I remember I did something similar for Dev Tools.

Comment: @RamRachum Here, I have edited it. It **should** now work. Just read the "Edit" part at the end.

Comment: Works like a charm, bounty awarded. I realize now that in addition, I will need a way to add custom.css immediately on page load before extensions are loaded, so if you know how to do that, please share.

Comment: Try adding `"run_at": "document_start"` in `manifest.json` file. That will load the js before the page loads and technically, that is before all the other extensions load (if they don't have `run_at` by themselves). I am **not** sure this would work.

Comment: With developer mode enabled, extensions certainly used to allow the author of stylesheets to change the look and feel of Chrome’s internal pages. I clearly remember writing a few to change the appearance of Chrome’s internal pages and developer tools. I have the whole of the CSS file that I wrote to customize the appearance of Dev Tools, if you would like to take a look. Chrome’s guide for customizing pages used to reside here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ThemeCreationGuide However, it now redirects to some bug collection page.

Comment: Although I have not written any extensions lately, which I used to do a lot during the 2012–2014 period, so I cannot say with certainty that the following should hold true, but the use of "location.url === 'chrome:'" in the .js file appears redundant. If you were to change matches directive in your manifest.json to "chrome:*", then I think it should do the job of matching for the proper protocol or for internal URLs starting with chrome: protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Copying the same content from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207474/custom-css-stop-to-work-in-32-0-1700-76-m-google-chrome-update)..

If you want to customize your devtools style, chrome.devtools.panels.applyStyleSheet has to be used. This feature is currently hidden behind a flag (--enable-devtools-experiments, requires relaunch of Chrome) and a checkbox (after enabling the flag, open the devtools, click on the gears icon, go to Experiments and check "Allow UI themes").

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "<name> DevTools Theme",
"version": "1",
"devtools_page": "devtools.html",
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

**devtools.html**

```
<script src="devtools.js"></script>
```

**devtools.js**

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open('GET', 'Custom.css');
x.onload = function() {
chrome.devtools.panels.applyStyleSheet(x.responseText);
};
x.send();
```

**Custom.css**

```
/* whatever you had in your Custom.css */
```

Comment: What makes you think this'll work for chrome:// pages?

Comment: Since it has got the correct version you were searching for (33+)..