# How can I permanently remove element from every webpage?

Tags: browser, safari, safari-extensions

I am running Safari, on a Mac with OSX El Capitan and I want a way to permanently remove an element from every webpage in a domain.

I do not want a temporarily make changes. I would like my answer to work in Safari, I have to say this twice because stupid editors and other users are continuing to point me to un-applicable solutions for firefox [here](https://superuser.com/questions/234952/understanding-css-for-user-styling-in-a-browser).

i.e. `https://www.google.com/search?num=100&client=safari&rls=en&q=test&oq=test` still has the same element blocked as `https://www.google.com/`

I am aware of extensions that do it for Firefox - "[Remove It Permanently](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/remove-it-permanently/)" and "[Yet Another Remove It Permanently](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/yarip/)" - but is there any way to do this in Safari, or would an extension have to be made to accomplish this task?

Comment: Are you using Mac or Windows? Bcoz safari in PC is different from safari on Mac OS. Read [creating extension on safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). You could inject javascript/css to do the element removals. BTW: Downvote: NOT ME. ;)

Comment: Let me know how this question is bad or should be improved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding CSS for user styling in a browser](http://superuser.com/questions/234952/understanding-css-for-user-styling-in-a-browser)

Comment: Not a possible duplicate as it is addressing a different browser. That is actually in the first line of the question if you would bother to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is use an extension that allows scripts to be added to a webpage.

I used the extension [Quickscript](http://canisbos.com/quickscript) for Safari. I created the following script to run and delete by classname every time I open the webpage:

```
removeElementsByClass('<className to delete>');

function removeElementsByClass(className){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    while(elements.length > 0){
        elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
    }
}
```

Another way is to delete by item id.

```
removeElementsById('<id to delete>');

function removeElementsById(id){
    var elements = document.getElementById(id);
    while(elements.length > 0){
        elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
    }
}
```

This can also be accomplished by creating a function using jquery.

```
removeElementsById('#<id to delete>');
removeElementsByClass('.<className to delete>');

function removeElementsByClass(className){
    $(className).remove();
}
function removeElementsById(id){
    $(id).remove();
}
```

Note: This solution is browser and OS independent. It only requires you find an extension that allows you to run scripts on websites.

[Custom JavaScript for websites](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija)  will work with chrome.