# Safari - Change specific websites components automatically

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

With Safari's version of AdBlock (and I suppose this is the same for all the other browsers), I can use its advanced options to block whatever I want in specific domains (or even in all domains), which allows me to remove *AdBlock blockers*, ads that AdBlock can't detect, and things that I don't like, like chats of specific websites and links that direct me to websites that are already dead, like Megaupload.

However, sometimes I just want to change a specific A tag text, or increase the size of a DIV tag, but that's not the purpose of AdBlock, and so it doesn't have that has a feature.

**My question is:** How can I **modify components** in websites in the same way that AdBlock lets me block them?

While writing the question, another one appeared in *Similar Questions* with that answer suggesting Quickscript:

https://superuser.com/a/984555/652028

However I tried it, and it doesn't seems to work with Safari 10.1, which is my version.

Comment: [tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/?browser=safari) will be able to do what you want (works for safari >= 5)

Comment: Rather than asking for a specific extension, it might be better to do a (minor) edit to ask "how might I change website element (etc)", as this may be (mis)construed as looking for a specific product recommendation. See [this faq](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software) for more info :)

Comment: @bertieb Ok, just updated my question

Comment: @DavidPostill Perfect! Tampermonkey solved my problem! If you could create an answer with that suggestion, I would happily recommend it has the best answer :)

Comment: @vitormm Answer written as per your request :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I change a specific A tag text, or increase the size of a DIV tag?

There are browser extensions that can handle this with ease.

The most common ones are [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (Firefox only) and [TamperMonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/index.php?ext=dhdg&browser=safari) (which works across a range of browsers).

In your case (Safari 10.1) you need to use TamperMonkey as it works with Safari >=5:

> Tampermonkey is a free browser extension and the most popular
>   userscript manager. It's available for Chrome, Microsoft Edge, Safari,
>   Opera Next, and Firefox.
>
> Even though some of the supported browsers have native userscript
>   support, Tampermonkey will give you much more convenience in managing
>   your userscripts. It provides features like easy script installation,
>   automatic update checks, a simple overview what scripts are running at
>   a tab, a built-in editor and there is a good chance that incompatible
>   scripts run fine with Tampermonkey.
>
> Tampermonkey is available for Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge, Opera,
>   Chromium, a lot of their derivatives like CoolNovo and Rockmelt and
>   also Firefox and some Android browsers. It's installed in just a
>   minute, so give it a try!
>
> ...
>
> [image]

Source [TamperMonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/index.php?ext=dhdg&browser=safari)